# How to Include namespaced Files in PHP?

Tags: php, apache2, doctrine-orm, xampp

I have a Problem developing in PHP. First I have to say that I'm not the experienced PHP developer on this Planet.

My Code/Problem is as followed:

In file `Controllers\TestController.php`:

```
  <?php
  namespace My\Test\Controllers;

  class TestController
  {
     public function HelloTest()
     {
          echo 'Hello!';
     } 
  }
?>
```

When I want to include this class in another php file like this

File `Models\TestModel.php`:

```
<?php
     namespace My\Test\Models;
     use My\Test\Controllers;         

     class TestModel
     {
       public function TestModelFunction()
       {
         $control = new TestClass();
         $control->HelloTest();
       }
     } 
?>
```

File `index.php`_

```
 <?php
      use My\Test\Models;

      $model = new TestModel();
      $model->TestModelFunction();
  ?>
```

That just won't work... I'll always get the following error:

> Class 'TestModel' not found!

When I now add:

`include_once 'Models/TestModel.php'` in index.php
AND
`include_once '..Controllers/TestController.php'` in `TestModel.php`
then it works...

Folder Structure:

```
Project
|-Models
|  TestModel.php
|-Controllers
|  TestController.php
|index.php
```

But do I really have to specify every Time where the files are?

Comment: This site works best if you ask one question at a time. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Another highly recommended read is: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). - Your code looks good for the namespacing btw, but keep in mind that you need to include the file with the class first before you can use it.

Comment: "but keep in mind that you need to include the file with the class first before you can use it" Means that I always have to write include_once ?

Comment: Normally Doctrine2 should take care of that automatically (that's called autoloading). I'm not that well with Doctrine2 that I can directly tell you what's wrong in your case (or where to look first), but I've edited your question so that it will hopefully is more clear and will attract more user.

Comment: And don't accept answers too early. If you accept one, you won't get more (correct/complete) ones.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. But the anwser beyond was good enough for this question. I think I have to write another question for the doctrine one.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer below is helpful, you should as well look for [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) - the IMHO correct way to do autoloading in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will always have to include the files that define your classes.

The namespace is just a way to package your classes together, not a way to automatically include PHP files.

If your are looking for a way to automatically include PHP files when needed, have a look on [autoload](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces *logically* separate code into different... well, *namespaces*. It has nothing to do with including the files that contain code for that namespace. So yes, you do need to `include` the file in some way or another (e.g. autoloaders) *in addition to* namespacing them.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use autoloader (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). You can find some good open source autoloaders out there.